# Pinch zoom for EditText

Tags: android

I need create EditText which user will be able to zooming using gestures. I implemented it via change scale in onDraw. But now I'm have problem. When I select some text, pin selector handle doesn't show correct. They show like EditText wasn't scale. Maybe someone have a same problem and know how solve this problem, or maybe you know some other variant to scale EditText.

Code of scale:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.scale(2, 2);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```